# How to show all column names of a TEMP table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My goal is to show all the column names of a temp table called `#foo`. This will turn into a stored procedure that can display the field names of any temp table. But right now, it doesn't work for a single hardcoded table.

I can run this and confirm the table exists: `select * from #foo`

However, this code produces an empty 2 column table. I was expecting to see 1 row per field in `#foo`.

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
Set @sql='SELECT 
            c.name AS FieldName,
            t.name AS DataType
        FROM 
            tempdb.sys.columns c
        INNER JOIN 
            tempdb.sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
        INNER JOIN 
            tempdb.sys.tables tbl ON c.object_id = tbl.object_id
        WHERE 
            tbl.name = ''#foo'''
Select @sql --This works
Exec(@sql)  --This returns a 2 column table but it is blank
```

Taking this a step further, when I try `Select * from tempdb.sys.tables`, I see that `#foo` has a name value like `foo_____________________________a1b4`. Given that this will be a stored procedure where `foo` is is one of the parameters, I don't know how to make use of this.

Comment: I assume you're creating the table somewhere dynamically and that's why you're struggling with this. Many ways to achieve this. For example: let name of your temporary table be a variable and EXEC dynamic sql statement providing the name from input parameter to the stored procedure.

Comment: @KamilGosciminski that's exactly my goal. The code snippet above is the stored procedure with a single temp table name hardcoded for now. Until this works, there's not much point making it a variable.

Comment: `WHERE tbl.name LIKE '#foo%'` https://dbfiddle.uk/HlWjoGGl Note that if you have the same procedure running simultaneously you may want to instead use `WHERE tbl.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#foo')` https://dbfiddle.uk/3MXwqsbs

Comment: For the temporary tables in your own session, you can use where object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#foo') . Unfortunately there's no great bulletproof way to figure out the real name of tables for other users/sessions as far as i know